# Removing PHP avatar action from Wordpress theme is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Background:**

I'd like to redesign the My Account area in WooCommerce to improve user experience and am working currently on my child theme files.

**Problem:**

My WordPress Theme adds an avatar to the dashboard that I'd like to remove and show somewhere else. I tracked down the Theme PHP class *(see bottom)* from the theme but somehow I cannot disable the code.

**Aim:**

I'd like to remove the action so the avatar isn't showing anymore.

**Attempt:**

I have tried the following code, but it's not working:

```
function remove_avatar() {
    remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( 'Listify_WooCommerce_Template_Account', 'setup_actions' ) );

}
```

**Question: How would I need to amend the code to achieve the desired outcome?**

I'd truly appreciate if someone could help me further!

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce "My Account" page.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 */
class Listify_WooCommerce_Template_Account {

    /**
     * Hook in to WordPress
     *
     * @since unknown
     * @return void
     */
    public static function setup_actions() {
        // remove account navigation
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation', 'woocommerce_account_navigation' );

        // add the account avatar
        add_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation', array( __CLASS__, 'add_avatar_to_dashboard' ), 99 );
    }

    /**
     * Add the avatar to the My Account dashboard page.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     * @return void
     */
    public static function add_avatar_to_dashboard() {
        if ( '' != WC()->query->get_current_endpoint() ) {
            return;
        }

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        printf(
            '<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-avatar">%s</div>',
            get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 100 )
        );
    }

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( 'Listify_WooCommerce_Template_Account', 'setup_actions' ) );
```

Comment: How are you calling `remove_avatar()` ?

Comment: @HowardE  Thank you Howard for the hint! I indeed forgot to hook the the remove function to something! Thanks a lot for the hint! It still didn't work, but I then set the priority to 1 and it worked for some reason. Do you want to post an official answer? I'll then accept and mark as solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the function reference for [remove_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/)

```
add_action( 'wp_head' , 'remove_avatar', 1 ); //note priority of 1
function remove_avatar() {
    remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( 'Listify_WooCommerce_Template_Account', 'setup_actions' ) );

}
```

Comment: This works with priority of 1, which I have added (but needs approval). Thanks again Howard!